# Why print() has side effects?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Why does print() method in Scala have side effects? All it does is to read, not to write. In other words, print() does not mutate anything.

I seems to be a "stupid" question, but sometimes the little things lead to big moves.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a "stupid" question, but it's also not a very good question for Stack Overflow, or at least not until you get a lot more rigorous about your definitions (and at that point I doubt there would be much of a question left).

Comment: I would say `print()` mutates stdout. It definitely doesn't read anything though. Generally the definition of "no side effects" is that a function takes an input, returns an output, and doesn't affect any other state.

Answer (score 11):

Not to have side effects for a function means that a call to it can be replaced by its return value. `print` does not return any value so if it was pure (it had no side effects) it could be replaced by NOT-OPERATION.

However, as you can see in your terminal, when you call `print` something happens: Some text gets printed in the screen. That is **not** NOT-OPERATION and therefore, `print` has side effects.

Answer (score 3):

As @lyjackal perfectly said `print()` mutates `System.out`.

For example this two definitions

```
def sumA = {
  val x = foo
  val y = bar
  val z = baz
  x + y + z
}


def sumB = {
  val x = foo
  val z = baz
  val y = bar
  x + y + z
}
```

should be the same if both `foo` and `bar`  have *no side effects*

So lines

```
println(s"By the way your result is $sumA")
```

and

```
println(s"By the way your result is $sumB")
```

should define identical behaviour from techical and user perspective

but consider this definitions of those functions

```
def foo = {
  println("Good to see you sir!")
  1
}

def bar = {
  println("I hate you")
  2
}

def baz = {
  println("Just joking")
  3
}
```

could now those behaviours seen as equivalent from user perspective?

Answer (score 1):

The output of the program could be connected to a rocket launcher, who understands, among others, the following command:

```
LAUNCH ROCKETS 1,7,13
```

Now, would you say that printing `LAUNCH ROCKETS 1,7,13` has no side effect? What if I told you that rocket 13 is targeted at your house?